# Birt report layout with SpagoBI studio

Tags: business-intelligence, fiware, spagobi

I am using SpagoBI studio to create BIRT report.
I inserted a Grid into my BIRT report but I coudn't move it from its place (the middle of the report, there is a table above it)
How can I move the Grid to the top of my report?

I tryied to move it with the mouse did not work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

actually you should be able to move the grid on top of the document.
Just pay attention to the cursor position: when dragging the grid, the cursor should be on the top left corner of the report.

Best regards

Davide